# typedef in the method's parameter

Tags: c++

I just learned about typedef. Suppose I have an instance:

```
private:
  typedef std::string int doubles abc;
```

when I make an accessors to instance abc:

```
returnType get(){...}
```

what should I put in the returnType? is it abc or the data type? thx

Comment: `typedef std::string int doubles abc;` What?

Comment: what you wrote is not correct. `typedef`s can only have the form `typedef T1 T2`, where `T2` becomes an alias for `T1`

Comment: Come with me. And you'll be. In a world of. Pure imagination...

Comment: Please explain what you think `typedef std::string int doubles abc;` does.  Also explain what you mean by "instance abc".

Comment: but, what should I do if I want to make an object that may contain string, integer and doubles? should I use type object and then cast it?

Comment: @AndyProwl: while what's written in the question is wrong, typedef still can have many other forms, like `T1 typedef T2, T3;`, for example.

Comment: @user1988385, You mean like `boost::variant`?

Comment: @user1988385: for that purpose you probably want to check Boost.Variant or use a union

Comment: @ybungalobill: you're right, thank you for reminding me

Comment: Concerning casting, don't do that unless you are 100% sure you have to. Concerning typedef, it's just an alias, like `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string<char>`. You never need it, but it saves you typing. Also, changing a single alias in one place is easier than changing it in multiple places, in case you want to change the type from e.g. `int` to `unsigned`.

Comment: @ybungalobill, Could you elaborate on the type before `typedef` in your example? I believe you meant `typedef T1 T2, T3;`.

Comment: @chris: No, I meant what I wrote. But it means the same thing as yours, since `typedef` is grammatically the same as `const` and thus can be reordered. :)

Comment: @ybungalobill, Interesting. I don't think I've heard that one :) I think I'll just *have* to write `unsigned char typedef byte;` or what not now to confuse a teacher or someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanted to do here. Your `typedef` is invalid syntax, and "doubles" is no C++ type (but probably just a typo). Examples for valid syntax would be:

```
typedef std::string abc;
typedef int foo; 
...
```

You can then use the `typedef` in function signatures, just like other types:

```
abc getValue();
```

Although you should put the `typedef` in the `public` part of your class if you want to use it in public member functions. And you should be aware that code outside of your class will always have to prefix the `typedef` with the name of your class, unless it is `typedef`'d again.

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    typedef std::string foo;
};

// Somewhere outside SomeClass
SomeClass::foo bar = ...
typedef SomeClass::foo localFoo;
localFoo fooBar = ...;
```

Apart from that: `typedef` does not provide any way to have a variable represent more than one type. C++ is a statically typed language, so this is not directly possible. You can, however:

- Use polymorphic classes with a common interface, instances of derived classes can then be treated like instances of the base class, but do different things
- Use a `union` and some discriminator to store what type it is currently storing
- Use `void*` and casting - **Not recommended!**
- Use something like `boost::variant`, `boost::any` etc. like suggested by others

*Edit:* Finally, on your use of the term "instance": It is usally used to refer to an instance of a class, i.e. a particular object belonging to a class. What you mean is a "member variable".

Comment: btw if I got something like this "typedef std::string a[]", what should I put on the "returnType"? is it a[]?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>`. I'd never recommend using C arrays in C++. But no, you would put just `a`, as it will be an alias for "array of std::string" and so you don't have to add the `[]` again.

Comment: I used array because the size of the data is fix. thx btw :)

Comment: You're welcome! ;) Ah I see - you can also use `std::array` for that on C++ 11-enabled compilers, or `boost::array`. But for your case, just using array is probably fine. You just have to be aware of the automatic conversion to pointer type etc.